# Change the function of a button based on drop down value in Angular

Tags: java, html, angular, drop-down-menu

I am currently generating a License Key based on the input from the user and passing to my Java code. The code to generate key is:

```
@PostMapping("/generate")
    public License generateLicense(@RequestBody License lic) {

        SecurityHashService service = new SecurityHashService();
        StringBuffer combinedKey = new StringBuffer(); 

        combinedKey.append("hardwareKey:").append(lic.getHardwareKey()).append(",").append("customerId:").append(lic.getCustomerId()).append(",")
        .append("product:").append(lic.getProduct()).append(",").append("msan:").append(lic.getMsan()).append(",")
        .append("msan:").append(lic.getCpe()).append(",")
        .append("connections:").append(lic.getConnections()).append(",").append("concurrent:").append(lic.getConcurrent()).append(",")
        .append("zmsVersion:").append(lic.getZmsVersion()).append(",").append("expiryDate:").append(lic.getExpiryDate().getTime());

        final String encryptedkey = service.generateKey(combinedKey.toString(), lic.getHardwareKey());
        lic.setLicenseKey(encryptedkey);
        return licenseDao.saveLicense(lic);
    }
```

The License class specifies all the parameters:
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Licenses")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

```
public class License {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String product;

    @NotBlank
    private String hardwareKey;

    @NotBlank
    private String licenseKey;

    @NotNull
    private Date expiryDate;

    @NotNull
    private Integer concurrent;

    @NotNull
    private Integer connections;

    @NotNull
    private Integer msan;

    @NotNull
    private Integer cpe;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date creationDate;

    @NotNull
    private String customerId;

    @NotNull
    private String zmsVersion;
```

In the Angular part: it takes all the values and generates the License. The component part is:

```
export class GeneratelicenseComponent implements OnInit {
  editable: boolean = false;
  licenseKey: string = "";
  submitted: boolean = false;
  form: FormGroup;
  minDate = new Date();
  allProducts:any=[];
  products: any=[];
  constructor(
    private generateLicenseService: GeneratelicenseService,
    private builder: FormBuilder, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.generateLicenseService.getProducts()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.allProducts = data;
      this.allProducts.forEach(element => {
        this.products.push({
          "value" : element["productId"],
          "viewValue" : element["productId"]
        })

      });
    });
    this.getDefaultConfig();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
        hardwareKey: ['', Validators.required],
        customerID: ['', Validators.required],
        product: ['', Validators.required],
        zmsVersion: ['', Validators.required],
        expiryDate: ['', Validators.required],
        concurrent: ['', Validators.required],
        connections: ['', Validators.required],
        msan: ['', Validators.required],
        cpe: ['', Validators.required]
    });



  }

  zmsVersions = [
    { value: '03.00.00', viewValue: '03.00.00' },
    { value: '03.01.00', viewValue: '03.01.00' },
    { value: '03.02.00', viewValue: '03.02.00' },
    { value: '03.03.00', viewValue: '03.03.00' },
    { value: '03.03.20', viewValue: '03.03.20' },
    { value: '03.04.00', viewValue: '03.04.00' }
  ]

  getDefaultValues() {
    let product = this.form.get('product').value;
    if(product=="MXK"){
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GenerateMxkLicenseDialog, {
       width: '450px',
       disableClose: true,
       autoFocus: true
     });
    }

    if(product="OSSXML"){
      debugger
      this.form.get('customerID').disable();
      this.form.get('zmsVersion').disable();
      this.form.get('concurrent').disable();
      this.form.get('connections').disable();
      this.form.get('msan').disable();
      this.form.get('cpe').disable();
    }
    if (product !=null) {
      //if (product == 'ZMS-VA' || product == 'ZMS-TIER 1' || product == 'ZMS-TIER 2' || product == 'ZMS-TIER 3') {
        let defaultArray = this.getDefaultConfig().filter((item) => {
        return item.id === product;
        });
        debugger
        this.form.get('concurrent').setValue(defaultArray[0].concurrent)
        this.form.get('connections').setValue(defaultArray[0].connections)
        this.form.get('msan').setValue(defaultArray[0].msan);
        this.form.get('cpe').setValue(defaultArray[0].cpe);
        this.form.get('expiryDate').setValue('');
      } else {
      debugger
      this.form.get('concurrent').setValue('')
      this.form.get('connections').setValue('')
      this.form.get('msan').setValue('')
      this.form.get('cpe').setValue('');
      var targetDate = new Date();
      targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() + 365);
      this.form.get('expiryDate').setValue(targetDate);
    }
}

  getDefaultConfig() {

    let defaultProductConfig: any=[];
    this.allProducts.forEach(element => {

      defaultProductConfig.push
        ({"id": element["productId"],
        "concurrent" : element["defaultConcurrent"],
        "connections": element["defaultConnections"],
        "msan": element["msan"],
        "cpe": element["cpe"]});
    });
    console.log("----->"+JSON.stringify(defaultProductConfig));
    return defaultProductConfig;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.allProducts[0]);
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    let product = this.form.value.product;
    let hardwareKey = this.form.value.hardwareKey;  
    let zmsVersion = this.form.value.zmsVersion;
    let customerID = this.form.value.customerID;
    let concurrent = this.form.value.concurrent;
    let connections = this.form.value.connections;
    let expiryDate = this.form.value.expiryDate;
    let msan =  this.form.value.msan;
    let cpe =  this.form.value.cpe;

    console.log("hardwareKey=====> "+hardwareKey);

    let licenseValuesArr = [
      {
        "hardwareKey" : hardwareKey,
        "product" : product,
        "zmsVersion" : zmsVersion,
        "customerId" : customerID,
        "concurrent" : concurrent,
        "connections" : connections,
        "expiryDate" : expiryDate,
        "msan" : msan,
        "cpe" : cpe
      }
    ];


    this.generateLicenseService.generateLicense(licenseValuesArr)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        debugger
        console.log(data["licenseKey"])
        this.licenseKey = data["licenseKey"];
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
```

In the form, I have a product field, which is a drop-down.

```html
<td colspan="2" width="100%">
                        <mat-form-field class="generate-full-width">
                            <mat-select placeholder="Product" formControlName="product" name="product" (selectionChange)="getDefaultValues()">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.value">
                                    {{product.viewValue}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && hasError('product', 'required')">Product is required</mat-error>
```

Now , lets say if the product name is "OSSXML", I want to disable all the input form  fields apart from Hardware Key and Expiry Date. I do not want to do this with a pop-up and not a separate button to generate license for this. I tried to disable those fields, set the value to just "" and applied multiple if-else conditions, yet each time it checks for values for others and in my application, I get error:

```
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=connections, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=cpe, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=zmsVersion, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=msan, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=concurrent, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=customerId, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
```

Please advice on what I should do. I am hoping to avoid adding new classes in my application, or creating separate services. Also, is this code need to be changed as the license generated is stored in a table called licenses. I want to store the license for OSSXML in same table.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/licenseGenerator")
public class LicenseController {
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because you have annotated these fields with `@NotBlank` in your entity class - that means JPA won't let you save new entity with these fields containing `null`.

What you can do is to remove `@NotBlank` from fields that might be empty in some cases.
Or, if removing annotations is not an option, you can make sure that angular application will send `{"connections": ""}` instead of `{"connections": null}`.
To do so, you can use [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) method to fill fields with `""` if chosen product is OSSXML, like this:

```
this.form.patchValue({
  connections: "",
  cpe: "",
  zmsVersion: "",
  msan: "",
  concurrent: "",
  customerId: ""
});
```

If you want to specify other fields, use values that you've used in `createForm()` method

Call it in `onSubmit()` method, just after check if form is valid.

Comment: I cannot make those fields not null. Also its imperative that no value be entered in those fields, that's why I was trying to disable. Also, can you give me advice on how to work with patchValue(), or an example.

Comment: The values are still coming as undefined in the licenseValuesArr and error 500 is shown in console.

Comment: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
 ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=zmsVersion, rootBeanClass=class com.licensegeneration.licenseGenerator.model.License,
 ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null',

Comment: Can you put `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value))` just before and after the `patchValue()` call and check if it applies values correctly?